# how to fit an image inside a box and vertical align it

Tags: html, css

I need to give access to the users to upload what ever pixels they want but it will be over 100x100 for their profile pic. The pic will be contained in SQUARE box.
But the problem is, when I upload a 100x100 or sizes similiar to that, it works good as expected. But when I upload an image with the pixels of 640x360 or anything similar to that sort (or widescreened), the image is scaled into the box well but however, it is not vertically aligned. I want the vertical-align to be in the middle, so how do I do that?

CSS:

```
#imgbox {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
#imgbox img {
  width:100%;

  position:relative;
  //I want the vertical align of the image to be in the center
}
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdW9h/1/

Comment: I would suggest using `background-image` so that you can use the `background-position` property.

Comment: Add this : #imgbox img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

Comment: I think that will ruin the image. I want the thumbnail to look not distorted, just scaled down, thats y I just want it to fit in a box

Comment: Yeah it will, you can use Explosion Pills' suggestion. That is a good bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things -

Use a class for your `imgbox` elements, IDs are used for selecting a single element in a given document.

Secondly, I suggest using one div with background-image properties, this way you can position it relatively.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgbox" style="background-image: url(http://plants.montara.com/ListPages/FamPages/showpix/ranunculaS/aqufor_a.JPEG)"></div>
<div class="imgbox" style="background-image: url(http://pictures.inspirationfeed.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Evolution_by_will_yen-500x500.png)"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgbox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm62n/)**

Comment: This is a good solution, but it does not work in IE8 (`background-position` is not supported). http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: That is not correct, `background-position` is supported by IE8+ with a valid `!DOCTYPE`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `background-size` is not supported.

Comment: The way you did is brilliant! However, how do I include the php tags inside the background-image url?

Comment: Yes, if you would like to output the image url from PHP you would do something like this - `style="background-image: url(<?=$myImageUrl?>)"` but that requires short tags enabled in your PHP ini file. The alternative is `<?php echo $myImageUrl; ?>`.

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst nvm got it. but, the background is not contained. THE BEST ANSWER!

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst, I realized i have to add the !important tag, now everything is working perfectly fine! AWESOME! THANKS ALOT!

Answer (score 4):

If you set a `line-height` on your container div, you can then use `vertical-align` on the image to position it. Also, you should use `max-width` and `max-height` to make sure the image is always contained within the box (assuming that's what you want).

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdW9h/7/

And here is the updated CSS:

```
#imgbox {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#imgbox img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks matthewpavkov, when I set the line-height to a 100, it added a new problem for the other image with perfect pixels. But I changed the line height to 95px, it looks centered and it doesn't affect the one with perfect pixels!

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure why the other image is moved down.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer @Cole?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `width` and `height` attributes on `img` to 100: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdW9h/4/

Resizing images in this way is generally not the best idea, though.  If you can resize the image with some sort of image library like GD I'd recommend doing that first.  It will save you some space on your server too.

Comment: +1 I thought of the same too but like you said not the best idea. GD library is the way to go. Alternatively, he can style it in the CSS itself by putting 100px for both but that again is not a good idea, the one I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This thing should fix your problem:

```
 #imgbox img {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;    
}
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
#imgbox { display:table-cell; }
```